# On this use of "as to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

I found the following sentence in a book about Einstein's special relativity,

> The equation *E = mc^2* has (at least in popular accounts)
>   been so exclusively linked to nuclear transformations **as to** divert
>   attention from its universality.

I don't think *as to* here means *regarding*. Another meaning I found of *as to* is *according to*, but this meaning too doesn't seem to fit in the context above.

So how does one interpret *as to* in the above construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step by step,...

> *There is an equation **E = mc^2***
>    *According to popular accounts (but not necessarily elsewhere)...*
>    *that equation has been exclusively linked to nuclear transformations* (but not to ***other*** things)
>    ***The extent to which*** that "exclusive link" has been made...
>    ***is so extreme...***
>    ***as to divert / that it diverts...***
>    *attention away from the "universality" of the equation*

Basically, the writer is saying that because "popular accounts" nearly always link ***E = mc^2*** to things like atomic bombs, most people aren't aware that it has other important implications (such as the underlying nature of the space-time continuum, the minimum meaningful "distance" between any two "locations", etc.).

---

For a simpler example,...

> *The noise was **so loud as to** hurt my ears*
>    (It was *very* loud. In fact, *so* loud that it hurt my ears.)